# Ether.li Problems

Tags: ether.li

Every time I try to submit a withdrawal from my ether.li wallet, it always send s 0 Ether, no matter how much I specify, example transaction ID: 0x3e2785b19d8ede1ff4b66808460eace7445d0883c0491f2aec5d498f5deec4f8 any idea ?

Comment: I have te same problem did you find any solution please?